# Retrieving Lake/Ocean/River names via GeoCoordinates?

Tags: xml, google-maps, geolocation

I am looking for a database that will allow me to collect the names of bodies of water based on GeoCoordinates.  Does anybody know anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?  http://www.geonames.org/advanced-search.html?q=&country=&featureClass=H&continentCode=

Note that according to http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=991a730ac41248428b48584ccf77b583, the service has a SOAP and REST interface, so you don't need to screen scrape.  The service is also (according to the latter page) free for both personal and business use.

(No idea how complete or reliable the info is.)

If you were hoping to do reverse geocoding (where you have coordinates to start with and the service will tell you the body of water that corresponds to those coordinates), it's possible this service can do it with the SOAP or REST interface, but I suspect it's not set up for that.  You may have to gather the data and create your own reverse geocoding interface or use a different service.